# How to redirect to error page if the value not exist?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, redirect, input

I have a JavaScript code to jump to a directory by typing its name. If the value is empty it shows error.html. The below JavaScript code works fine but I am going to add a feature that if the directory not exist show error2.html.

```
<form action="javaScript:jump()" name="f1" onsubmit="return check()">
<input type="text" name="k1" value="" placeholder="Enter the name of the directory"/>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="s1" value="check">
</form>
```

```
<script>
    function jump() {
        window.location.href = document.f1.k1.value;
    }
    
    function check() {
        if (document.f1.k1.value=="") {
            window.location.href='error.html';
            document.f1.k1.focus();
            return false;
        }
            return true;
}
</script>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: There's no way for the client to check if a directory exists. You need an AJAX function that returns this information.

Comment: Maybe we can modify the `jump()` function to check if the directory exists before redirecting to it using AJAX request -- https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#y2436dsbw7r9kz9yey0etj

Comment: @UncleIroh Thank you for the code. That is exactly what I need. but there is one problem. If the directory name exist, it does not redirect. Instead, it shows the "error2.html" again. Could you please solve it.